# Backend to Backend authentification with OAuth2

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0, backend, cloud-foundry

**What I'm trying to do**

Right now I'm working on a Java Spring Backend for a Both which manages the request he gets from a NLP from api.ai and gives back corresponding information. Now I'd like to interact with different services that use OAuth2 to get information/data from there as well.

**What I did so far**

I have added my credentials for the service in my `application.properties` file. But only found a solution that a user can for example log-in with his facebook credentials on my service.
But I need to have my service to authenticate on the other service (with the given credentials from my properties file), to gather data from there.

Do you guys know a solution, tipps, tricks for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand the logic should be following.

As you have SSO (OAuth2 based) you need to login just once and get token(s) from OAuth2 service (access token and refresh token). The access token is included in the request headers when you call any of your services.
Now Service1 must call Service2 using the same auth info.

In the Service1 you call OAuth2 service to check whether the token is valid. If yes all you need is to use the same token to call Service2.

So just extract the token from request headers and add to the headers of request you send to Service2. Could be done e.g. by adding a Filter and storing the auth info in a ThreadLocal variable (or inheritable ThreadLocal if you generate new threads by e.g. running Jobs).

Service2 in turn also checks the token by calling OAuth2 service but the token is valid.

For me that's all you need.